# FF Xpather to Nokogiri -- Can I just copy and paste?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, scraper

I was doing this manually and then I got stuck and I can't figure out why it's not working. I downloaded xpather and it is giving me: /html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table as the path to the item I want. I have manually confirmed that this is correct but when I paste it into my code, all it does is return nil

Here is my code:

```
a = parentdoc.at_xpath("//html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table[1]")
puts a
```

If I do something like this:

```
a = parentdoc.at_xpath("//html/body/center")
puts a
```

I get a huge chunk of text from the page. I can keep adding elements until I hit tbody then it returns nil again. I even tried something like: //html/body/center/table/*/tr[3] and that  did the same thing returning nil

What am I missing?

Comment: What does the HTML look like? And your Nokogiri XPath has a `[1]` at the end that your xpather XPath doesn't, is that a typo?

Comment: @Mu Does the 1 matter in the context of .at_path? I agree it's different, but that's left over from trying different things. Here is an example page. http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3034295 I want the first comment and the author line.

Comment: The `[1]` doesn't matter with `at_xpath` as it takes the first one anyway, the **real** structure of the HTML does matter though and browsers will change the HTML in ways that Nokogiri won't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that Firefox is inserting a `<tbody>` element that is not present in the HTML. When you use xpather, it is working from the HTML that the browser is using (rather than the raw HTML that ycombinator.com is returning) and it finds this path:

```
//html/body/center/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table
```

Nokogiri will be working with the raw HTML so you want this

```
//html/body/center/table/tr[3]/td/table
```

When I apply that XPath to the URL in your comment:

```
doc.at_xpath('//html/body/center/table/tr[3]/td/table').text
```

I get this output:

```
"csoghoian 1 hour ago  | link | parent2 responses:1. Chrome is the only major browser not to ...
```

Comment: Why do browsers insert crap into the HTML?

Comment: @NoahClark: People use crappy invalid broken HTML so the browsers have to fix it. The `<tbody>` isn't required but the browsers probably add it when they're normalizing the HTML, inserting it probably removes some special cases from the rendering system. Try sending a browser `<p><ul><li>pancakes</li></ul></p>` and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for all your help with this question and the other one. I really appreciate it. If I do that in chrome it adds the html, head, and body. Is that what I'm supposed to see?

Comment: @Noah: Depending on the browser it will become `<p></p><ul>...</ul>` since you're not supposed to put a `<ul>` inside a `<p>`. This sort of chicanery is why page scraping is such a big pile of ugly hacks and nonsense.