# Is there anything special to consider using HTML scraping using xpaths?

Tags: html, ruby, xpath, nokogiri, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from a location in HTML using Nokogiri with xpath. The xpath I am using is:

```
 /html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]
```

The xpath points to:

```
<td class="anatxt" nowrap=""> CELL TXT DATA <div id="div0" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute">
```

The code is simple:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w

require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

page1 = Nokogiri::HTML(open('test1.html'))

a = page1.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]").text
p a
```

It works with other shorter paths but it only returns `""` for this specific case.

Why this might be happening? What am I missing, or is there a funny Nokogiri behavior due to some bug? Any pointers are welcome.

Comment: Can you post some (complete) example markup for us to experiment with?  Gist it if it's long. https://gist.github.com/

Comment: No, there is nothing special to consider, except that your XPath looks exceptionally fragile. You should be anchoring on more semantic aspects of the page (like `id` and `class` attributes) if possible. As @d11wtq says, you need to show us a real example of the XML to use.

Comment: thanks people! it is actually the `tbody` tag added by mozilla which is not originally there. it works if you remove it from the xpath

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **tbody** tag may not actually be there.
Some browsers will add them when they aren't there but Nokogiri will not.

Comment: I had this problem as well. You can see my stack overflow question about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540506/ff-xpather-to-nokogiri-can-i-just-copy-and-paste

Comment: Correct, some browsers add `tbody` and that acts as a red herring. It's always best to look at the source text when building an XPath accessor rather than rely on the browser to generate the accessor.

Comment: removing `tbody` tags worked. damn browsers(mozilla in this specific case)! thanks pguardiario :)